# socket IO error net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on client

Tags: node.js, socket.io, intel-edison

Following this demo here exactly. The only difference is that I am using an edison instead of arduino.

[cylonjs socketIO demo](http://cylonjs.com/blog/2015/02/05/using-socketio-with-cylonjs-api/)

This is my server code *app.js*.

```
var Cylon = require('cylon');
 Cylon.robot({
    name: 'chappie',
    connections: {
        edison: { adaptor: 'intel-iot' }//,
        //led: { driver: 'led', pin: 13 }
  },

   devices: {
        maxbotix: { driver: 'maxbotix', pin: '0' },
        led: { driver: 'led', pin: 13 }
    },
    work: function (my) {
    /*
    STUFF TO DO!
  */
    }    
    })  
Cylon.api(
'socketio',
{
    host: '0.0.0.0',//Is this correct??
    port: '3000'
 });

Cylon.start();
```

The 'blink-client' is exactly the same as in the demo except I am hardcoding the actual IP to the edison where we define the device. ie

> device = io('http://ip of edison:3000/api/robots/chappie/devices/led');

When I runn app.js, the socketIO server correctly launches and I see

```
[2015-02-17T20:04:12.813Z]  INFO -- : Initializing connections.
[2015-02-17T20:04:13.116Z]  INFO -- : Initializing devices.
 [2015-02-17T20:04:14.646Z]  INFO -- : Starting connections.
[2015-02-17T20:04:14.650Z]  INFO -- : Starting devices.
[2015-02-17T20:04:14.667Z]  INFO -- : Working.
[2015-02-17T20:04:14.703Z]  INFO -- : Cylon API Server is now online.
[2015-02-17T20:04:14.704Z]  INFO -- : Listening at https://127.0.0.1:3000
```

But when I try and run the blink-client.html in a browser on a PC on the same network I get the ***ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED***

I am using cylon-api-socketio *version "0.2.2"* and nodejs *version 0.10.28*.

In the client PC in a browser if I simply go to

```
http://actual ip of edison
```

I correctly see the default page for the edison showing me that I have the correct IP and my app.js is running. 
Really not sure what my next debugging steps should be. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Where are you seeing the "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"?  In the browser console?

Comment: yes.fixed. discovered I had an older version of Cylon and simply had to upgrade